# How i return only one recordset from multiple select of a stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

This is my SProcedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `etracking`.`validarAcceso` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `etracking`.`validarAcceso` (IN pusuario VARCHAR(30),IN ppassword VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN

  DECLARE encontrado INT;
  SET encontrado = 0;
IF encontrado = 0 THEN
  SELECT usuarios_distribuidores.nombre, usuarios_distribuidores.apellido1,
  usuarios_distribuidores.apellido2, distribuidores.nombre, count(encontrado) FROM
  usuarios_distribuidores INNER JOIN distribuidores ON
  distribuidores.iddistribuidor =  usuarios_distribuidores.iddistribuidor
  WHERE email = pusuario AND password = ppassword;
END IF;

IF encontrado = 0 THEN
   SELECT * FROM usuarios_centro_acopio WHERE email = pusuario AND password = ppassword;

END IF;

IF encontrado = 0 THEN
  SELECT * FROM usuarios_admin WHERE email = pusuario AND password = ppassword;
END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There's no point to `encontrado` if it's never updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options. You can use a union or a join. It depends on your structure.

```
 SELECT * FROM usuarios_centro_acopio WHERE email = pusuario AND password = ppassword
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM usuarios_admin WHERE email = pusuario AND password = ppassword;
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM usuarios_centro_acopio c, usuarios_admin a WHERE c.email = a.email and cpassword = a.password and email = pusuario AND password = ppassword
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the queries in the same condition, so that you can use `union all`:

```
IF encontrado = 0 THEN

  SELECT usuarios_distribuidores.nombre, usuarios_distribuidores.apellido1,
  usuarios_distribuidores.apellido2, distribuidores.nombre, count(encontrado) FROM
  usuarios_distribuidores INNER JOIN distribuidores ON
  distribuidores.iddistribuidor =  usuarios_distribuidores.iddistribuidor
  WHERE email = pusuario AND password = ppassword;

  UNION ALL

  SELECT * FROM usuarios_centro_acopio WHERE email = pusuario AND password = ppassword;

  UNION ALL

  SELECT * FROM usuarios_admin WHERE email = pusuario AND password = ppassword;

END IF;
```

Comment: The column data types need to match at each position in the SELECT clause for that to work.  That's hard to determine when two queries use `SELECT *` notation...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Good point. There should of course not be any queries that doesn't specify which fields to return in a production query...

Comment: Hi thanks a lot but u tell me to group the queries in  one but i need to get the recorset of only one select  depending on the if  i put above... for example if the first select gets the record the other selects returns null recordset, so how i should do if i dont want to see those others null recordsets...

Comment: in sql server i use SET NOCOUNT ON to prevent extra resultsets... but in mysql i dont know how to do that...

Comment: @Alejandro: Just union the queries, and the empty queries will just end up as adding no rows to the result.